# Do I need to re-install Latex or is there another problem?

Tags: texshop, macos

I've been writing a math paper for a couple of years using TexShop on a Mac. The Mac told me I should upgrade from OS 10.15.7 to 11.something and I permitted it. Then, the User account I use froze during sign-in so I had to do a complete wipe and restore of my hard disk from a TimeMachine backup. I got everything back but, now, when I hit CMND-T in a LaTeX doc, I get this message in the console window and it won't generate the PDF.

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

 kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
 mktexfmt: No such file or directory
 I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered installing [MacTeX2020](https://tug.org/mactex/)?

Comment: @Mico  I tried MacTeX in Sept 2019 and it did not work well on my Mac. Do you recognize my problem with TexShop? It has worked wonderfully until the OS mess that required me to wipe and restore my hard disk. Could it be a missing file that a re-install could fix or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you claiming that you can use TeXshop without MacTeX to compile a TeX or LaTeX document? TeXshop is a front-end editor, MacTeX is the back-end TeX distribution. If you can't update the OS, then at least find a version of MacTeX that's less ancient than MacTeX2020. The site that the link in my earlier comment points to lets you download older versions of MacTeX.

Comment: @Mico I downloaded and installed TexShop and it worked great. I just don't know why it stopped working after the wipe/restore event.

Comment: I have no knowledge of your TimeMachine settings, but it sounds like application programs (such as MacTeX2019) were not part of the backup and restore process. If that's the case, the presumably easiest fix is to download and install MacTeX once more.